# Is there any way to disable pop-up UI animations on the Sony RX1R II?

Tags: sony, camera-controls

The Sony RX1R II has annoying and unnecessary pop-up animations. For example, when in `M` mode and changing the shutter speed, an animated "shutter speed scale" appears on screen. This is annoying because it covers the bottom of the image (both in LCD and EVF mode) and unnecessary because the shutter speed is already instantly displayed in the info bar.

Is there any way to turn off these animations?

(Research already done: I've gone through all the menus, hunting for a relevant option.)

Comment: If there is no option provided in the menu, then only a software modification/update would be the way. But modify the software is often not possible or voids the guaranty. 
And I'm just curious: is there any other visualization of the actual settings beside this fancy pancy animation? Google images don't show any other status display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open menu:
Tab 2 (Gear icon) > Page 2 > Exposure Set. Guide > Off

Comment: Incredible! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by changing the available display options in the menu.

On my Sony (A77II) there are 3 preview display options, one including the mentioned scale and a info display option.

The 3 preview display options are also switchable for the viewfinder.

Comment: Thanks. The RX1R indeed has a display (DISP) option which shows shutter speed and aperture scales overlaid on top of the image full-time, and disables the pop-up animation. However it has the same problem of covering the image.

Comment: Check out the manual, https://docs.sony.com/release/DSC-RX1_RX1R_guide_EN.pdf
Pages 143 to 146, The 'No Disp. Info.' modes don't cover any part of your image and only display the basic settings.

Comment: The 'No Disp. Info.' modes still feature pop-up animations, which cover the image, when settings are adjusted.

Comment: Interesting, could you snap a picture of the no disp info mode with the popup showing and add it to your question?

Comment: Here's a video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MgxBffT6b5A

Comment: @ruief oh wow, I can imagine those get annoying quickly! I'll check if I can find anything to fix that but I'm afraid it's just build that way